# Write particular names and values in IEEEtran conference in latex

Tags: fonts, ieeetran

I am using IEEE bare_conf latex template and I want to write particular variable names or values such as the word "eqnarray" in figure below in the middle of a paragraph.
[image: snapshot from IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf]
Are there standardized fonts, commands for this? I see that the IEEEtran_HOWTO guide itself is using different font for these kind of stuff but I can't figure out what produces that.

Answer (score 1):

The font used here seems to be the standard LaTeX monospace/teletype font defined by `\ttdefault`. There are various ways to use it:

1. Using a font switch `{\ttfamily ...}`,
2. using a font command `\texttt{...}`, or
3. if you need to typeset special characters such as the backspace `\` in LaTeX commands, there's `\verb|...|`.

Note that `\verb` doesn't use braces as delimiter but you are free to choose any character that doesn't appear in the text you want to set.